# How to achieve complex nested query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, subquery

I'm trying to achieve this complex schema.

```
{

relation1_id : Number,
... 
...

item_caption: [
    {
        caption: '',
        subcaption: '',

        products: [
            {
                pid: 1,
                quantity: 5
            },
            {
                pid: 2,
                quantity: 52
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ... 
    }
]}
```

I did consider JSONB but i may need statistics of the child schemas ( products_heading & heading_items ). I heard JSONB isn't well verse with statistics.

What i'm trying to achieve :-

> Each Headings will have a heading , subheading and a products property
>   Each heading will have multiple products

My current schema. I'm having a hard time writing CRUD api point for this. How would you tackle this ?

[image]

Comment: What is your actual requirement..

Comment: @Ajay Added my requirement

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to create that JSON structure in a query? Or are you designing a database schema?